# Is it possible to use the URL to change the CSS being applied?

Tags: html, css

I have two pages that have related topics, and share a significant amount of data & text between the two pages.

Since these two pages are both linked to from the same location, side by side, I am wondering if I can use an argument with the link to change the CSS being applied and have ALL the data on one page.

The original setup:

> domain.com/subdir/one.page.php
>
> domain.com/subdir/two.page.php

Can I use this instead?

> domain.com/subdir/full.page.php?one
> domain.com/subdir/full.page.php?two

And with that, have the page selectively use the CSS `visible` attribute to change what is actually displayed on the screen?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do here - hide content based on which page you are on or style things differently for each page, with a lot of commonality between both pages?

Comment: @PointedEars - What exactly are you trying to tell me? I just re-read the FAQ and failed to see what you were trying subtly convey.

NightMICU - I was trying to avoid having to duplicate the header, metadata, and a host of other stuff which is common between both pages. That's how the idea was spawned. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: For future reference, there's no need to change the title of your question to include "ANSWERED".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the CSS cannot be affected by the URL.

Instead, you should use a server-side programming language to only display the appropriate content.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but at least I know whether or not to try, thanx.

Comment: Surely this isn't true. Javascript could be used to dynamically alter the page based on the url parameters and thus change what CSS is applied (either by loading different stylesheets, manually adding CSS styles, adding classes to attributes, etc.) A server side approach might be best but that isn't to say it couldn't be done clientside.

Comment: I kinda figured that, but I was hoping for a very simple "if... then" type setup. No biggie, I can just create the two separate pages.

Comment: @Chris Ah yes, but some browsers dont have javascript enabled.

Comment: @AnishGupta: Although true it is very rare to find a browser that doesn't support javascript.

Comment: @Chris they may just have it disabled. i know a few schools and offices that have explicitly disabled javascript in all their computers

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP `include` statements to prevent duplication.